# Why do I have to state 'atomic=False' when I change model name in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Okay so I was following Django 2.0 tutorial on the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/) 
when I realized I named a model 'Questions' instead of 'Question'. (I'm new to Django)

I already did

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
$ python manage.py migrate
```

so I thought I could just repeat this to apply the change.

Django asked me if I wanted to rename so I said yes.

```
(venv) H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\mysite>python manage.py makemigrations
Did you rename the polls.Questions model to Question? [y/N] y
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls\migrations\0002_auto_20180804_0935.py
    - Rename model Questions to Question
```

But when I tried to migrate, Django wouldn't run the migration and showed me this error.

```
(venv) H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying polls.0001_initial... OK
  Applying polls.0002_auto_20180804_0935...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 330, in database_forwards
    new_model._meta.db_table,
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\django_tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 84, in alter_db_table
    ) % old_db_table)
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Renaming the 'polls_questions' table while in a transaction is not supported on SQLite because it would break referential integrity. Try adding `atomic = False` to the Migration class.
```

I googled and [one Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549068/django-db-utils-notsupportederror-in-sqlite-why-not-supported-in-sqlite) said I should add `atomic=False` but he never explained why.

I also googled the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/writing-migrations/) for 'Non-atomic migrations' but still don't see why it's needed for a simple model name change. (It's rather hard to understand what it is for me to be honest.)

Is it really supposed to be like this to change a model name? Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

> **Non-atomic migrations**
>
> On databases that support DDL transactions
>   (SQLite and PostgreSQL), migrations will run inside a transaction by
>   default. For use cases such as performing data migrations on large
>   tables, you may want to prevent a migration from running in a
>   transaction by setting the atomic attribute to False:

Comment: Did you try deleting `polls\migrations\ ` and then run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: @Mint No I just added `atomic=False` on `polls\migrations\0002_auto_20180804_0935.py` and it worked. Did I suppose to delete `polls\migrations\' ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

you can `set atomic=False` at SQLite or `use PostgreSQL, MySQL` for atomic table rename.

**Detail**

Maybe you already know, this error is raised at `django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 84, in alter_db_table`

If you want to know why you can see this code. (this is overriding to `base/schema.py` )  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py#L77

```
def alter_db_table(self, model, old_db_table, new_db_table, disable_constraints=True):
    if disable_constraints and self._is_referenced_by_fk_constraint(old_db_table):
        if self.connection.in_atomic_block:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ # if checked atomic, raise NotSupportedError
            raise NotSupportedError((
                'Renaming the %r table while in a transaction is not '
                'supported on SQLite because it would break referential '
                'integrity. Try adding `atomic = False` to the Migration class.'
            ) % old_db_table)
        self.connection.enable_constraint_checking()
        super().alter_db_table(model, old_db_table, new_db_table)
        self.connection.disable_constraint_checking()
    else:
        super().alter_db_table(model, old_db_table, new_db_table)
```

And then you can compare default Postgresql or Mysql (these are not overriding `base/schema.py` ) https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L399

```
def alter_db_table(self, model, old_db_table, new_db_table):
    """Rename the table a model points to."""
    if (old_db_table == new_db_table or
        (self.connection.features.ignores_table_name_case and
            old_db_table.lower() == new_db_table.lower())):
        return
    self.execute(self.sql_rename_table % {
        "old_table": self.quote_name(old_db_table),
        "new_table": self.quote_name(new_db_table),
    })
    # Rename all references to the old table name.
    for sql in self.deferred_sql:
        if isinstance(sql, Statement):
            sql.rename_table_references(old_db_table, new_db_table)
```

**Summary**
Django's Sqlite3 does not allow atomic option with renaming table.
You can use Django's Postgresql, Mysql or etc (allowing atomic table rename).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Yes, this is the way to change the model name. You are doing it right, just as it is explained in [non-atomic migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/) you mentioned.

**Long answer:**

From [SQLite Tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/):

> SQLite is a transactional database that all changes and queries are
>   atomic, consistent, isolated, and durable (ACID).
>
> Atomic means that when you commit a transaction, either the entire
>   transaction is applied or not.
>
> By default, SQLite operates in auto-commit mode. It means that for
>   each command, SQLite starts, processes, and commits the transaction
>   **automatically**.

Now imagine you have several tables in database and you decided to rename one of them. SQLite starts automatically a **transaction** and within this transaction it tries to rename your table. However, your table is referenced by other tables, for ex., and so an exception is raised (as you can see from the code that was presented earlier by @EunChong Lee).

```
if self.connection.in_atomic_block:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ # if checked atomic, raise NotSupportedError
        raise NotSupportedError((
            'Renaming the %r table while in a transaction is not '
            'supported on SQLite because it would break referential '
            'integrity. Try adding `atomic = False` to the Migration class.'
        ) % old_db_table)
```

So, when you use in you migration file the line `atomic = False`:

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False
```

you skip this exception and then you proceed with renaming your table, yeah, doesn't look all that great to me, but well.

What is happening behind the curtain is not clear for me either, I guess one should look more into the code from `django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py` to get a deeper understanding of how references are fixed with `atomic=False` and at what moment we should be more careful while implementing the change.